# Tableau: Displaying the each selected measure name in bar chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have a bar char report that I created that contains three measure names: 1) Complete 2) Opted In 3) Completion rate. How can I display the measure name below the bar chart similar to the screen shot below from SSRS report that I created. I tried looking for options with tableau environment, but was not successful. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard color legend will show all three items however, it would look more like:

[image]

Note that the standard color legend only shows the color, not the bar versus line. If you need to replace the standard legend with a custom one as you are showing, you can add an image to your dashboard which looks exactly as you desire.

Comment: Can you please share where I can do this in tableau? Thanks

Comment: To get the dual axis bar + line chart look at http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/dual-axis-bar-chart-multiple-measures

Comment: To put an image on your dashboard, drag "image" off the objects panel onto the dashboard and point to the image file you want displayed.